# how can I know whether a user has watched my full rewarded video ad or skip ad in android?

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I am using Rewarded interstitial ads in my app. 
Is there any method to know whether any user has watched a complete rewarded video or not in my rewarded video ad?

I need to place a rewarded video in my app, and I want to know whether any user has watched the full video or not? How can I know that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can check if an user has completely watched a rewarded video or not. All you need to do it to implement the rewarded ad video listener.

```
yourAdObject.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
```

and implement RewardedVideoAdListener's methods in your activity. 
It will override these methods :

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {

}

// The following listener methods are optional.
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
}
```

The onRewarded(RewardItem reward) is called on watching the video completely.

For more information about Video Ads read the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video)

Comment: this doesn't describe how would I go about telling whether the ad was skipped

Comment: Is there a server side check solution?

Answer (score 8):

I used the following code to check if a user has watched my full rewarded video ad or skipped ad in between:

```
int adLeaveCheck = 0; //Declare a global variable

RewardedVideoAdListener rewardedVideoAdListener = new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
            adLeaveCheck = 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

            if (adLeaveCheck != 2){
               Toast.makeText(this, "Why are you not watching full ad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Thank you for watching full ad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

            adLeaveCheck = 2;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

        }


    };


    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(rewardedVideoAdListener);
```